# Defining an interface for an object which is extended by another interface

Tags: typescript

I'd like to define an interface with unknown properties for an object which is extended by known properties from another interface.

**This is what I've tried:**

```
public async dispatchMessage(): Promise<{} extends IHasResponseFormat>
```

I expected that this is the definition for this method returns a Promise which resolves to an Object, which contains the properties defined in `IHasResponseFormat`. However that doesn't work apparently, VSCode hints at

> [ts] Return type of public method from exported class has or is using
>   private name ''.

**My question:**

How can I define the return type which means "any object which contains the properties defined in `IHasResponseFormat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I define the return type which means "any object which contains the properties defined in `IHasResponseFormat`?

Just use the `IHasResponseFormat` type then. That is exactly what it means to use an interface as a type.

```
public async dispatchMessage(): Promise<IHasResponseFormat>
```